# PHP Mysql Resultado da pesquisa

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Boa tarde

Estou a tentar resolver isto há dois dias sem sucesso e gostaria da vossa ajuda pessoal :)

As tabelas são as seguintes:

```
Chaves` (
  idChaves int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nomeChave varchar,
  estadoChave int(1) ,
  situacao varchar(10) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idChaves`)
)
```

Vigilantes:

```
TABLE `Vigilantes` (
  `idVigilantes` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PORVigilante` int ,
  `nomeVigilantes` varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idVigilantes`)
)
```

Colaboradores:

```
CREATE TABLE `Colaboradores` (
  `idColaboradores` intAUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomeColaboradores` varchar,
  `apelido` varchar,
  `POR`,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idColaboradores`)
```

Locacoes:

```
TABLE `Locacoes` (
  `idLocacoes` intAUTO_INCREMENT,
  `horaSaida` timestamp ,
  `horaEntrada` timestamp ,
  `Vigilantes_idVigilantes` int,
  `Colaboradores_idColaboradores` int,
  `Chaves_idChaves` intL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idLocacoes`),
  KEY `fk_Locacoes_Vigilantes1_idx` (`Vigilantes_idVigilantes`),
  KEY `fk_Locacoes_Colaboradores1_idx` (`Colaboradores_idColaboradores`),
  KEY `fk_Locacoes_Chaves1_idx` (`Chaves_idChaves`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Locacoes_Chaves1` FOREIGN KEY (`Chaves_idChaves`) REFERENCES `Chaves` (`idChaves`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Locacoes_Colaboradores1` FOREIGN KEY (`Colaboradores_idColaboradores`) REFERENCES `Colaboradores` (`idColaboradores`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Locacoes_Vigilantes1` FOREIGN KEY (`Vigilantes_idVigilantes`) REFERENCES `Vigilantes` (`idVigilantes`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Resumindo para o **Colaborador** requisitar uma **Chave** ao **Vigilante**  utilizo a tabela **Locacoes** que leva o ***Vigilantes_idVigilantes,*** ***Colaborador_idColaboradores*** e o ***Chaves_idChaves***.

Até aqui tudo bem, porém quando faço a pesquisa via PHP com o seguinte código:

```
$rs = $connection->prepare("SELECT  * from  Locacoes INNER JOIN Colaboradores INNER JOIN Vigilantes INNER JOIN Chaves  WHERE DAY(horaSaida) =  DAY(now()) GROUP BY idLocacoes");

if($rs->execute())
{
     while($registro = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {

        echo "<TR>";

        echo "<TD>" . $registro->idLocacoes . "</TD>";
        echo "<TD>" . $registro->horaSaida." </TD>";
        echo "<TD>" . $registro->horaEntrada . "</TD>";
        echo "<TD>" . $registro->Colaboradores_idColaboradores.
        echo "<TD>" . $registro->Vigilantes_idVigilantes . "</TD>";
        echo "<TD>" . $registro->Chaves_idChaves . "</TD>";
        echo "<TD>" . $registro->nomeVigilante."</TD>";
        echo "<TD>" . $registro->nomeChave."</TD>";
        echo "<TD>" .$registro->nomeColaboradores."</TD>";
```

Os resultados da **Locacoes** obtenho perfeitamente porém o nomeVigilante, nomeChave e nomeColaboradores vem tudo repetido deve ser porque a função (PDO::FETCH_OBJ) me devolve apenas o primeiro nome da coluna.

Tenho isto provisoriamente no seguinte endereço

Se tiverem outra solução também gostaria de ouvir.

Muito obrigado desde já.

Cump

Comment: Há outro nome de chave e cobrador cadastrado, que deveria aparecer?

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho condições de testar o seu código, mas acredito que o problema esteja na forma que você está fazendo a junção das tabelas. Quando se utiliza o `JOIN` em tabelas relacionadas por chave estrangeira. É necessário especificar uma condição(`ON`):

```
...
$rs = $connection->prepare("SELECT  * from  Locacoes 
INNER JOIN Colaboradores ON Colaboradores.idColaboradores = Locacoes.Colaboradores_idColaboradores
INNER JOIN Vigilantes ON Vigilantes.idVigilantes = Locacoes.Vigilantes_idVigilantes
INNER JOIN Chaves  ON Chaves.idChaves =  Locacoes.Chaves_idChaves
WHERE DAY(horaSaida) =  DAY(now()) GROUP BY idLocacoes");
...
```

Não pude testar o código, mas dessa forma deve funcionar.

Um conselho. Use nomes mais simples nas chaves estrangeiras. Por exemplo: `colaboradores_id` em vez de `Colaboradores_idColaboradores`. Assim ainda da para perceber facilmente a função do campo e escrever as consultas vai ser mais fácil.

Comment: Perfeito! Desconhecia que o ON era sempre necessário. Muito obrigado está a funcionar perfeitamente. :) Tks

Comment: Então marca a resposta como correta.

Comment: Como faço isso ? Obg